# Django Create multiple views

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am new to Django. I have to create multiple views and create buttons for them in the main page. I have created different view for different filters of the table. I now have to create buttons in main page to redirect to different views . Can't figure the changes in urls.py and templates.

**here is my code :**

**`views.py`**

```
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models import Min
from .models import airdata
from .tables import AirdataTable


class AirdataListView(SingleTableView):
    model = airdata
    table_class = AirdataTable
    template_name = 'dashboard/data.html'
    q = airdata.objects.aggregate(alpha=Min('pol_max'))['alpha']
    queryset = airdata.objects.filter(pol_min= q).order_by('-state')

class AirdataListView2(SingleTableView):
    model = airdata
    table_class = AirdataTable
    template_name = 'dashboard/data2.html'
    q = airdata.objects.aggregate(alpha=Max('pol_max'))['alpha']
    queryset = airdata.objects.filter(pol_min= q).order_by('-state')
```

**`app/urls.py`**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import AirdataListView,AirdataListView2

urlpatterns = [
    path('page1/', AirdataListView2.as_view()),
    path('page2/', AirdataListView.as_view()),
]
```

**`project/urls.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**`template`**

```
  {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>Air Data</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
          {% render_table table %}
      </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Django will try to match the given url with one of the paths defined in `urls.py`.

In your case, you have two views that match the empty pattern, so Django is returning the first match and you wont be able to access your second pattern.

Try this on your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('page1/', AirdataListView2.as_view()),
    path('page2/', AirdataListView.as_view()),
]
```

Chances are you will eventually want to do more complex stuff and pass parameters into your urls so perhaps its a good idea to [check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) for more info about them.

Comment: for the solution you proposed it's showin 404 error. Though I will try through url dispatcher.

Comment: It also depends on the settings you added to you `urls.py` on your project folder (you should have at least 2 `urls.py`). Try posting the other one so I can understand your pathing right.

If you dont have any path that matches the empty string `''`, them seeing a 404 at the start is a correct behavior.

With the settings we have here you only have two pages:
`127.0.0.1/page1` and `127.0.0.1/page2`, any other page will be a `404`.

Comment: yeah I got it. Thanks. How do I create links for them In the main page.like to redirect them. Thanks

Comment: You will need to change your code a little bit and use the `{% url %}` on your template html, unfortunately this comment section is not suited for writing big chunks of code. But you can check some tutorials online.

[This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) should have all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as Django will run the first view match the url pattern which is  the first one in your case. The problem you are handling can be solved by GET parameters. So read about it.